# What is the most "idiomatic" way to get Unix seconds from PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, datetime, unix-timestamp

I'm used to using the .NET Framework `DateTimeOffset` to get Unix seconds.

```
PS> ([datetimeoffset] '2020-01-01').ToUnixTimeSeconds()
1577854800
```

But, I'm writing a PowerShell script and thought I'd try to be as "idiomatic" as possible. It seemed like `Get-Date` would do the trick, but the results are different.

```
PS> Get-Date -Date '2020-01-01' -UFormat %s
1577836800
```

It seems like `Get-Date` is synonymous with `DateTime`, using my local timezone, by default. The only way I can get a UTC date from `Get-Date` is another .NET method call.

```
PS> (Get-Date -Date '2020-01-01').ToUniversalTime()
```

And, now, to get Unix seconds, I can pipe again?

```
PS> (Get-Date -Date '2020-01-01').ToUniversalTime() | Get-Date -UFormat %s
```

That's an awful lot of piping for what I thought would be a simple expression... any other ideas?

Comment: Only a guess, but I'd wager it's a time zone difference between your time zone and UTC

Comment: Is there anyway to get a UTC date from `Get-Date` _and_ format the output w/o piping? Like: `(Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() | Get-Date -UFormat %s`

Comment: The analysis is right - `[DateTime]` is unspecified type (will be local time), but `[DateTimeOffset]` is UTC. Why does piping matter?

Comment: .NET Framework 4.6 or higher has [DateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeSeconds()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.tounixtimeseconds)
) - `[DateTimeOffset]::Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds()`

Comment: @kuujinbo - Read the first sentence of the OP's question (you may want to delete your superfluous comment)

Comment: @Bill_Stewart it’s annoying  and chaining one get-date into another just for formatting was a surprise to me, hoping to minimize surprise!

Comment: Without piping you could do `get-date ([datetime]'2020-01-01').ToUniversalTime() -UFormat %s`, but that seems kind of convoluted to me.

Comment: Be aware that PowerShell has issues with UNIX timestamps not being correctly calculated: ["UNIX time stamp" different between windows and linux](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2195), [Some fixes in Get-Date -UFormat](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/6542).

Comment: Also - why use Unix time seconds at all? PowerShell can compare `DateTime` (or `DateTimeOffset`) objects.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I'm writing a script that needs to feed data into a Linux system and working with Unix seconds is far preferable over there (I know that pwsh is cross-platform, too, but the downstream system is not pwsh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so, until `Get-Date` becomes timezone aware or we get a new cmdlet... it seems we have to use the `ToUniversalTime` method. It's especially important to consider because [this bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2195) seems to only effect formatting Unix seconds if you *haven't* converted to Universal time (a [fix is merged](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/6542), but who knows what release that's in).

So, the *best* we can do is probably something like this:

```
PS> Get-Date -Date (Get-Date -Date '2020-01-01').ToUniversalTime() -UFormat %s
```